# Mysql Performace issue with LEFT-JOIN and Group By

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, group-by, left-join

I am having 2 tables EMP & EMP_DTL.I am using LEFT JOIN as below.

```
SELECT EMPDEL, 
    EMPYEAR, 
    EXCODE, 
    CONCAT(COALESCE(TCODE, ''), COALESCE(INTCODE, '')) AS INTCODE, 
    (   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ECODE SEPARATOR ' ') FROM EMP_DTL 
        WHERE EMP_DTL.DTL_EID = EMP.EID AND ETYPE='')  AS ECODE, 
    COUNT(SSN)                                         AS SSN,
    MIN(ESRP)                                          AS ESRP, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CURCODE SEPARATOR ' ')       AS CURCODE 
 FROM EMP 
 WHERE EAND='TOY' 
    AND EMPYEAR IN ('2014', '2015') 
    AND EGORY IN('G') 
    AND (EHIND = 'N' OR EHIND = 'FALSE') 
    AND EMP.SSN IS NOT NULL 
    AND ESRP > 0 
 GROUP BY EMPDEL, EMPYEAR, EXCODE, INTCODE, ECODE
```

and the table structure are this way,

```
CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `EID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ETYPE` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `SSN` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPDEL` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMPYEAR` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESCODE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EIAL` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EAND` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ETUS` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESRP` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EHIND` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EGORY` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ECODE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXCODE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TCODE` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INTCODE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CURCODE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EAREA` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EID` (`EID`),
  KEY `SSN_IDX` (`SSN`),
  KEY `EMPDEL_IDX` (`EMPDEL`),
  KEY `EMPYEAR_IDX` (`EMPYEAR`),
  KEY `EAREA_IDX` (`EAREA`),
  KEY `ETUS_IDX` (`ETUS`),
  KEY `EAND_IDX` (`EAND`),
  KEY `ESRP_IDX` (`ESRP`),
  KEY `EHIND_IDX` (`EHIND`),
  KEY `EGORY_IDX` (`EGORY`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `emp_dtl` (
  `DTL_EID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SSN` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ECODE` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ETYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DTL_EID`,`ECODE`),
  KEY `EMP_DTL_IDX` (`DTL_EID`),
  KEY `ETYPE_IDX` (`ETYPE`)
)
```

**Problem is Query is executing around 30sec for  10000 records.**

I tried adding these things in the above query to increase the performance,

1) Added  "WHERE" clauses

2) Added appropriate indexes on the two tables for the ids and the columns in the WHERE clauses.

3) Executed execution plan to make sure that my indexes are used. And this is the output of execution Plan.

```
ID   SELECT_TYPE             TABLE      TYPE   POSSIBLE_KEYS                                                KEY                     KEY_LEN     REF      ROWS   EXTRA
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
'1', 'PRIMARY',             'EMP',     'ref', 'SSN_IDX,EMPYEAR_IDX,EAND_IDX,ESRP_IDX,EHIND_IDX, EGORY_IDX', 'EGORY_IDX',            '2',        'const', '13',  'Using where; Using filesort'
'2', 'DEPENDENT  SUBQUERY', 'EMP_DTL', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,EMP_DTL_IDX,ETYPE_IDX',                              'ETYPE_IDX',            '48',       'const', '1',   'Using where; Using index'
```

Should I add anymore Indexes?
Can some one help me in optimizing this Query further to reduce execution time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are actually not joining, but starting a separate lookup in EMP_DTL for every record of EMP. Try this:

```
SELECT EMP.EMPDEL, 
    EMP.EMPYEAR, 
    EMP.EXCODE, 
    CONCAT(COALESCE(TCODE, ''), COALESCE(INTCODE, '')) AS INTCODE, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(EMP_DTL.ECODE SEPARATOR ' ')          AS ECODE, 
    EMP.COUNT(SSN)                                     AS SSN,
    MIN(EMP.ESRP)                                      AS ESRP, 
    EMP.GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CURCODE SEPARATOR ' ')   AS CURCODE 
 FROM EMP 
 LEFT JOIN EMP_DTL ON EMP_DTL.DTL_EID = EMP.EID AND EMP_DTL.ETYPE=''
 WHERE EAND='TOY' 
    AND EMPYEAR IN ('2014', '2015') 
    AND EGORY IN('G') 
    AND (EHIND = 'N' OR EHIND = 'FALSE') 
    AND EMP.SSN IS NOT NULL 
    AND ESRP > 0 
 GROUP BY EMPDEL, EMPYEAR, EXCODE, INTCODE, ECODE
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the left-join offering from Dirk, you have individual indexes on different fields which won't really help as much as a multiple-key index.  Try putting an index on your table to cover primary elements of the WHERE clause AND elements of the group by... But having this many columns might be too much and not practical.  Your result set on just the WHERE clause keys may be enough to improve performance.

create an index on...  ( EGORY, EAND, EMPYEAR, EHIND, SSN, ESRP )